# "<trim-directive-whitespaces>" directive not removing white spaces in Websphere 7.0 Application Server

Tags: java, jsp, websphere, web.xml, websphere-7

I am trying to remove line breaks and empty spaces on the rendered HTML page using an entry in `web.xml`

```
<jsp-config>
      <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
      </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>


<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    metadata-complete="false"
    version="2.5">
```

this does not seem to work. I have a WAS 7.0 server. I found on multiple posts claiming this works on Tomcat. Does this work in WAS?

Answer (score 0):

Which WAS version do you have? According to [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014413926#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014413926) it should be fixed in WAS v 7.0.0.9. So I'd suggest to update to the latest fix pack and give it a try.

Comment: Hi Gas, thank you for replying. My version seems to be later than required one. Here is what I found.
<pre>Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                     IBM WebSphere Application Server - ND
Version                  7.0.0.27
ID                       ND
Build Level              cf271250.01
Build Date               12/13/12
Architecture             AMD (64 bit)</pre>

Comment: sorry about the formatting above, i copied with line breaks, but it seems to ignore that

Comment: @user1908728 Ok, looks like it should be there. So maybe you should create a PMR in IBM Support.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working here either in my 8.5.5.8. Either at the web.xml level or the individual JSP level. Or does "template text" mean only in `${var}`, not in like `c:out` or `fmt:formatDate`, I wonder?